# Gulp Minify SVG to a string

Tags: gulp

I replace the IMG tag with the inline code from the SVG file. How do I minify SVG code before I insert it in the js file?

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/js/**/*.js')

        .pipe(replace(/<img src="\/img\/icons\/(.*?)">/g, function(match, p1) {
            return fs.readFileSync('./src/img/icons/'+p1, 'utf8');
        }))

        .pipe( jshint() )
        .pipe( minify({
                ext:{
                    min:'.min.js'
                },
                ignoreFiles: ['*.min.js', '*-min.js']
            }))
        .pipe( gulp.dest('./build/js') )
        .pipe(notify({ message: "JS done.", onLast: true }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it, replace the line:

```
return fs.readFileSync('./src/img/icons/'+p1, 'utf8');
```

with:

```
return fs.readFileSync('./src/img/icons/'+p1, 'utf8').replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '');
```